# App Engine Connected Android Application no Google account

Tags: android, google-app-engine

I followed tutorial https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/appeng_android_run_debug
but when I debug the project and click add account I dont see Google as an option ... I only see Coporate and Email.

I must register phone with Google account to receive messages from C2DM, so why there is no that option?

Thanks.

Comment: You have to start emulator with target name = Google API (API level 8 or more).

Answer (score 1):

Yes you need a Google Account.

Because Google App Engine sends the Message to the C2DM Server and from there to your registred device.
For more Information visit: https://developers.google.com/android/c2dm/

I had the problem that the tutorial didn't work like I wanted. (I couldn't connect my Google Account) 
So I debugged it directly on my mobile device with usb-connection and there it worked.

Comment: You need to create emulator with Google API support.